# Which password encoder for Spring Security's DaoAuthenticationProvider: MD5 or SHA-256?

Tags: java, spring, passwords, spring-security, password-protection

Is there any real difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MD5 has some known vulnerabilities, whereas SHA-256 does not. Because of this I would suggest SHA-256.  [Here's a link that describes why.](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/836068) Although I have no idea if they are actually affiliated with the US Department of Homeland Security, the site does explain what I mean.

[The Wikipedia article on MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) also discuses the weaknesses.

Comment: Happy to help :-) oddly enough the official spring security book that was released for version 3 not long ago doesn't mention this at all and still advocates the use of MD5